# How to access linked entry of a linked entry?

Tags: php, contentful

So I've upgraded to the most recent Contentful PHP 2.0 SDK, from the 0.7.0-beta I've been using. I noticed that I wasn't able to get a linked entry from a linked entry anymore.

I would receive an error of:

**Fatal error** Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Encountered unexpected resource type """" while constructing link. .../ResourceBuilder.php on line 452.

I looked through the Changelog, but couldn't pinpoint what had changed this.

Thanks, in advance.

```html
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query;
$query->setContentType(PAGE_TYPE)
    ->where('fields.slug', $slug);
$entries = $client->getEntries($query);

$entry = $entries[0];

## get linked entry

<?php foreach ($entry->getBlocks() as $block) : ?>

## get linked entry of linked entry 

$aside = $block->getAside();
```